# Binding dynamically changed control/getting to render on screen

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to create a form that dynamically changes the dropdown (control2) based on a valid text box entry (control1). When the user enters a value into text box (control1) I want dropdown (control2) to bind a specific string to the value, and also render the word 'Date' on the drop down. The drop down has two values only: 'Selected' or 'Date' where as if the user enters wrong value into text box the 'Selected' value displays and nullifys dropdown (control2) value. I am not able to get this to both show the 'Date' box and 'Selected' box as well as update the control2 respectively, can anyone assist?

form creation:

```
form: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
  control1: (null),
  control2: {value: null, disabled: true}
})
```

checking valid text box entry:

```
validControl(): boolean {
  if(this.control1.value !== null && this.control1.value !== ''
&& this.control1.valid) {
    return true;
}
else {
  return false;
}
```

Here is a [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mgtpeh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) that shows the front end as well:

In a nutshell here is what I am looking for:

- User types valid entry into text box (control1)
- Dropdown shows 'Date' and binds 'EDTEV' into control2
- If user deletes out text in control1 then Dropdown shows 'Selected' and nullifies the value in control2

Comment: Where does control3 come in? You have only described control1 and control2 but in your demo you are using control1 and control3

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding of the question this may help:

1. modified the control3 to control1 in *ngIf condition
2. modified *ngIf condition check a bit(when there is no value  and
   when something is entered u can change this as per your requirement)

only modified the app.component.html

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>

<form [formGroup]="form">
  <input type="text" formControlName="control1"><br><br>
  <select formControlName="control3">
    <ng-container *ngIf="form.get('control1').value">
    <option *ngFor="let items of response" [value]="items.code">{{items.description}}</option>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngIf="!form.get('control1').value">
    <option>SELECTED</option>
    </ng-container>
  </select>
</form><br>

<button (click)="test()">TEST</button>
```